# Phylogenetic Tree Contruction From Triplets

Tags: algorithm, tree, phylogeny

I've been given the task of writing a short program to create a phylogenetic tree (all data in the leaf nodes) given a data set of triplets, of the form (**b**, **c**, **a**), where **a** is the least common ancestor of **b** and **c**.

I have a copy of Aho, Sagiv, Szymanski, and Ullman's paper "Inferring a Tree from Lowest Common Ancestors with an Application to the Optimization of Relational Expressions" (SIAM J. Computing vol 10 no. 3, Aug 1981). I've gotten partway through the description of the algorithm, but am stuck on the portion labeled "induction", where the leaves are selected by their common ancestor. Looking on-line for information finds me with pages that tend to skip over this part. I assume it's obvious and I'm missing something?

What I have so far (in perl, not broken up in subroutines yet):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Graph; 
use Tree::DAG_NODE;

my @triplets;
while (<>) {
    push @triplets, [ split ];
}

#
# In order to generate the G(L) extract the first two
# columns(edges) of @triplets to make the edges of the auxiliary
# graph. Then pass this array of edges to the Graph constructor.
#
my @auxiliary_edges = map { [@$_[0,1]] } @triplets;

my $graph = Graph->new(
    undirected => 1,
    edges => \@auxiliary_edges
);

my @components = $auxiliary_graph->connected_components;

die "No Tree!" if (@components == 1);     # No tree!

my $root = Tree::DAG_Node->new;
$root->name('_ROOT');

#
# Each connected component is a set of leaves.
#
for my $component (@components)
{
    print "Component (leaf set): [", join(", ", @$component), "]\n";

    #
    # To be written: induced(), which is the heart of my problem,
    # and add_phylo_tree(), which isn't.
    #
    my @matches = induced(\@triplets, $component);
    add_phylo_tree($root, @matches);
}

print_tree($root);    # To be written. I'm using Data::Dumper right now.
exit(0);
```

Data File:

```
b c a
a c d
d e b
```

Searching (https://www.google.com/search?q=phylogenetic+tree+from+triplets is typical) hasn't gotten me useful information so far, although [Triplet Methods](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=0772DCA9649E3596FE5319A41B0F3193?doi=10.1.1.135.7740&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (PDF) came close (I suspect there's a mistake in the graphs though).

I also read "Using Max Cut to Enhance Rooted Trees Consistency" by Snir and Rao, IEEE/ACM Transactions on Computaional Biology and Bioinformatics, vol 3 no. 4 Oct-Dec 2006), which helped clarify some issues, but not the one that's blocking me.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you measuring distance between nodes, e.g. Hamming distance..?

Comment: Also, could you maybe post the paper's 'induction' bit? I can only see the abstract.

Comment: I'm not measuring distance at all. The least common ancestor is the first common ancestor node that's found when one travels up the tree from two separate nodes.<br>I will try to summarize the induction code in another update. Sorry for the delay in replying, I wasn't notified of your comment.